# Ubuntu 22.04 VM randomly started crashing after 15 minutes of use

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, vmware, crash, memory-leak

Using VMWare 16 on a Windows 10 PC.  Started last Friday, the Ubuntu 22.04 VM would start getting slower and slower, and will eventually freeze.  Only solution is to force end task of VMWare 16 and restart the VM.

After 10 - 30 minutes, the VM will once again become slower and slower and eventually crashes.  I have no idea where to even start to debug.  Only application open on VM is PyCharm Professional 2022.2.  I tried giving the VM slightly more RAM and storage, both to no avail.

Host computer runs completely fine with no lag.  It almost feels like theres a memory leak on the Ubuntu VM.

Any hints on how to debug this?

EDIT: The VM loses memory by itself.  I just left it on for 15 minutes (no applications or interaction) and it froze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be caused by USB ports not being properly supported in VMWare.  After I unplugged my USB 2.0 charging port for my iPhone, the memory leak stopped.